# Problem with html drop down list

Tags: html, select, drop-down-menu

I am having problem with my html drop down select box. I have long list of items in select box therefore it goes outside of my screen. it doesn't shows scroll bar. Please help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the `size`:

```
<select ... size="1">
```

Comment: This converts drop down into list box

Comment: @Future: yes I know, but doesn't it solve the problem of no scroll bars?

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the HTML and any css that styles the select? Inspect the select element in Firebug and see what the overflow attribute is set that (it should default to auto and create the scrollbar if necessary).

```
<select id="#long-select> 
    <option ...>...</option>
    <option ...>...</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Then the correspond CSS:

```
#long-select { overflow: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your page in IE, should show all elements.

I think it is a bug in Firefox, that the list element is always aligned to the select field. IE does not show the list outside of the screen.

Comment: this problem is on both IE 8 and Firefox 3.6